# Iterate over firebase database nodes flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to iterate through the customers available and get the posts of every customer and show it inside a listview.

However, if i specify the database reference as `final postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Customers available').child(Uid).child('Posts').orderByChild('timestamp');`, I get only the user's posts.

Below is my code for building the listview and another is my database reference. Thanks `final postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Customers available')`
[This is my Firebase Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGApM.png%60FutureBuilder()

```
          future: postsRef.once(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              lists.clear();
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
              values.forEach((key, values) {
                lists.add(values);
              });
              return new ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: lists.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 4),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150),
                                  image: DecorationImage(image: FirebaseImage('gs://tipy-98639.appspot.com/profile_pic'))
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/dp.png')),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150)
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('NAME', style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'myriadpro',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 1.7
                                ),),
                                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical *  1,),
                                Text(lists[index]["text"],
                                  maxLines: 20,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'myriadpro',
                                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 1.7
                                  ),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
            return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),),
                    Text('Loading your posts... ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'myriadpro'
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
          }),`
```